# How easy (or hard) is to move a Rohloff speedhub from one bicycle to another?

Tags: internally-geared-hub, rear-wheel

I have two 26" bicycles and I am considering investing in a super expensive Rohloff speedhub.

I would like to know if it would be possible to easily move the wheel with the rohloff hub from one bike to another - assuming of course that both have already been set up for it (shifter, cable, and everything).

Thank you

Comment: The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohloff_Speedhub) looks like the OEM version should be able to.

Comment: Er ... must be too late at night ... the Wikipedia *article* looks like ...

Comment: FWIW I've been doing this for years. You might be surprised at how well different anti-rotation devices work (Rohloff offers 4 or 5) outside their designed scenario. The main hassle or expense is moving the shifter or buying multiple shifters. I have one Rohloff that's been used in at least 7 bikes so far, and usually have at least one more bike than rear wheel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If both bikes have a frame which is set up for it, with the long drop-out on the Thorn pictured below and the EX Box below it, then it would be the work of 5 minutes. Just unscrew (possibly by hand) that big nut on the ex-box, remove the wheel and put it onto the other bike.

[image: Rohloff-specific frame with EX-box]

The only issue to remember is to always shift to the same gear (say, the lowest) before you remove the EX-box and ensure the shifter is in that position when you reconnect, otherwise you won't be able to get into all the gears.

If, on the other hand it's a more complicated set up with a reaction arm like this:

[image: Rohloff mounted with reaction arm]

Then it might be more complicated. Then again, perhaps the arm can be disconnected with a single pin, I haven't tried it. The two cables under the black flexible plastic cable covers will also need to be disconnected. I'm not sure how hard that is.

Comment: Thank you. What I am planning to do is using two normal MTB frames (short, vertical dropouts) with the rohloff chain tensioner. Would you think it'd be as easy then? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure. It might depend on how easily you can remove the pin at the left-hand end of the tensioner arm, below the chain-stay. I assume the tensioner arm is attached more securely to the hub and would move with it. You may be able to get more detailed information on the Thorn forum: http://www.thorncycles.co.uk/forums/index.php?board=25.0

Comment: The block on the chainstay is designed to allow the torque arm to be easily released:
https://www.rohloff.de/fileadmin/_processed_/5/a/csm_handbuch02_065_4.en_a88adc97ed.png